# Where should define Entity model class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I wore a java based app and used Spring Boot

This is the model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task_list")
public class Task implements Serializable
```

And this is the Config class that Spring boot uses it to start :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller", "dao", "service"})
class Config {


    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
```

And this is The Application :

```
@SpringBootApplication()
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Config.class);

    }
}
```

So When i run the application it works and creates all bean BUT
when i want to interact with Database , Hibernate got this error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: model.Task
```

I Think this is because of there is not any persistence.xml to mapping 
model class,

SO what should i do in Spring boot app ?
where should put that xml?
is there any Annotation that tells to spring boot to map the model classes ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: If properly configured, you shouldn't need to declare any `DataSource` nor any `EntityManager` yourself. Spring Boot manage them for you under the covers.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-separate-entity-definitions-from-spring-configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Xtreme Biker , I solve the problem

i just add the model package in `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

```
@Bean(name = "entityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new     LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("model");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());

        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: You don't even need to create an entity manager. You just need spring repository interfaces and define the entities there. Then you add the repositories in some service logic and voila pretty fast and easy database handling.